# One div fixed, other auto fill page

Tags: html, css

I have this script:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AjgNM/86/)

I managed to make the `#middle` DIV auto fill the page, but I need to make the right div fixed and the content still behave the same. I am really stuck at this point and and don't know what to do. I need an idea.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="middle">Middle</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#middle, #right {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
}

#right {
    width: 150px;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

#middle {
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: By "fixed" you mean `position: fixed` or what exactly?

Comment: Yes, when I use the mouse scroll I need the right div to stand where it is with and only scroll the `#middle` div content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the properties of the right panel like this:

```
position:fixed;
right:0;
top:0;
```

you'll get the functionality you want. The problem is, the fixed property removes the div from the "normal flow", and it will overlap the middle div. To fix this you can set the position of the middle div, then adjust the width using the CSS calc() function:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width: calc(100% - 150px);
```

The 150px is the width of your right div. Note the spaces surrounding the -, they're important!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AjgNM/88/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply position fixed on #right?

```
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

Comment: but you also need to change the middle with, see if this works http://jsfiddle.net/AjgNM/87/